# C# .Net CF SqlCeDataAdapter DataSet Fill is slow

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I´m having a little trouble with database performance in a Compact Framework application (SQLServer Compact Edition database).

What I do is:

1. Query the database for some data with the SqlCeDataAdapter, in return I get 6 rows with data
   `sqlCeDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, Sql_Connection);`
2. I then use a SqlCeDataAdapter Fill Method to fill a dataset with data.
   `sqlCeDataAdapter.Fill(resultSet);`
3. Loop the dataset..

When I have 300 rows of data the whole function takes less than a second to perform but if I have ~10 000 rows of data then it takes about 6-7seconds (and it´s too much in my application).

In both cases it returns exactly the same rows, but the Fill Methods slows it down…

Is the database queried first when the fill method is called or?

Can I do something about it else than keeping the number of rows down?

Also if I change the query so the database returns 0 rows it still takes the same time...

Best Regards

Edmund

Comment: post your actual code...

Comment: What does the actual query look like?  Is the target table indexed properly?  7 seconds indicates there's something wrong that we're not seeing (though I agree with ErikEJ's suggestion to abandon the DataSet).

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you avoid using DataSet on .NET CF, as it consumes too much memory, and essentially copies the database in RAM. Use SqlCeResultSet if you need databinding, otherwise just use SqlCeDataReader

Comment: Hi Erik! Thanks for your answer... Well I´ve been trying the SqlCeDataReader as well but it´s still slow (6-7). The only thing that's better is when the query is not returning any rows then there is no delay... // Edmund

Comment: You can also investigate bypassing the query processor to get max speed, using .Seek and .TableDirect

Answer (score 1):

Thanks’ all for your help...

I found the trouble, the table was not indexed at all...

It was suppose to be but the creator of the database had missed it.

Now everything works real fast (Also changed to SqlCeDataReader instead of the dataset).

Again, Thanks ErikEJ and ctacke...

/edmund